# where password and username are stored on linux based router?

Tags: linux, router, firmware

i extracted the HG630v2 firmware which is linux based i want to know the firmware username and password, I tried looking into etc/passwd1 which contain the following

```
    root:x:0:0:admin:/bin:/bin/sh
nobody:(null):0:0:tr140 user:/mnt:/bin/sh
web:x:2073:2073:web:/bin:/bin/sh
upnp:x:2189:2189:upnp:/bin:/bin/sh
cwmp:x:2065:2065:Linux User:/bin:/bin/sh
telnetd:x:2076:2076:telnetd:/bin:bin/sh
console:x:2162:2162:console:/bin:bin/sh
dhcps:x:2048:2048:dhcps:/bin:bin/sh
sntp:x:2059:2059:sntp:/bin:bin/sh
```

Comment: The password is hashed. The hash value is one way, there is no way of know what the password is, by just having the hash value

Comment: the data is likely in /etc/shadow, but as ramhound mentions it contains only one-way hashes. you would need tools like hashcat to try to break them, but we won't provide further assistance on that.